# iPhone Application Permission

Tags: iphone

I want to know if it is possible to have two separate applications in iOS Domain where 
1) One application is the background application
2) Other acts like Foreground application

The foreground application will use background application for fetching data, data processing and maintaining its database. The user will need to install both applications on his device and for this it should be like this that if user installs one app (say foreground or UI app) it will automatically guide user to install another app. Have heard that something like of this sort is possible in android and applications like voice recognization etc does that.

Also the background application will start running as soon as we boot our device and foreground will launch only after user launches it by clicking on the icon.

Possible advantages in my mind
scenario where one can come with more than one foreground apps. So both of foreground applications can use same background applicatons for maintaining database. This way there will be only one app maintaining database for two different foreground apps on a single device

The background will be the main app will be doing all heavy lifting such as fetching data from server, checking update at regular time intervals and maintaining data base.

Not sure if something of that sort is possible in iOS and is permissible on app store?

Thanks

Comment: There are a very limited amount of scenarios where an iOS can run in the background. I suggest you look at the multitasking guide on the apple website - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

Comment: Also, what you are describing sounds exactly like the MVC design pattern. Breaking up the model and controller from the view.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of something like this, especially not on an iOS device.

I don't think it will be accepted for one reason: two different testing teams will test each app. Because the apps require each other, neither app would function. If prompted to install the "other" app, testers would be unable to do so, because it would not be published, because the other team was unable to test it, because the original app was not published. (run on sentence).

It would be like a circle...

My thoughts...

Answer (score -1):

What you are saying could be down with one app and multiple classes and in fact is a fairly common design pattern.  You set up one class as the data model, and use background threads and process to keep the data up to date.  The other class handles the user interaction on the main thread.  Do a few searchs on Model View Controller design pattern and check the link below

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: Yeah, but he's not asking if it can be done. He's asking if it can be done with two different apps and whether it would be allowed.

Comment: True, but I am explaing a better way to accomplish the primary goal and function of the app, which still solves the overall problem.  His description is very close tot he MVC design pattern...just like the other comment...